# How can I create different design (as fragment in Android) in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want to create different designs in my page and keep them in a container in my page. With arrows, I should navigate between my different designs. How can I achieve that in Windows Phone 8 SDK? Is there a something like fragment in Android in WP8 SDK?

Here is a drawing of what I want to create:

[image]

Comment: That looks like a WP8's PivotPage or a PanoramaPage.  Just without the arrows.  You can add the arrows inside its respective container though.

Comment: Isn't that changing page? I have some static buttons under fragment. Can I create different designs and change those designs only inside fragment with PivotPage?

Answer (score 0):

Use Pivot Page .This will look better than Fragment activity.